# How to set time zone for historical price quotes retrieved using ccxt?

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, ccxt

The python example below from ccxt will fetch historical price quotes.

https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/examples/py/binance-fetch-ohlcv-to-csv.py

The code does not show how to set the time zone. How can I set the fetched price quote timestamp to Asian HK/Singapore time zone?

I am using python 3.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just pass datetime string with timezone like `2017-08-17T00:00:00+08:00` into `scrape_candles_to_csv` function from [your example](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt/blob/master/examples/py/binance-fetch-ohlcv-to-csv.py) ([Asian HK/Singapore has UTC+8 timezone)

Method `exchange.parse8601` correctly handled strings with timezone

```
>>> exchange.parse8601('2017-08-17T00:00:00+08:00')
1502899200000
>>> exchange.parse8601('2017-08-17T00:00:00Z')
1502928000000
```

So I ran

```
scrape_candles_to_csv('binance.csv', 'binance', 3, 'BTC/USDT', '1h', '2021-12-17T00:00:00+08:00', 100)
```

And got

```
100 candles in total from 2021-12-16T16:00:00.000Z to 2021-12-20T19:00:00.000Z
200 candles in total from 2021-12-16T16:00:00.000Z to 2021-12-24T23:00:00.000Z
260 candles in total from 2021-12-16T16:00:00.000Z to 2021-12-27T11:00:00.000Z
260 candles in total from 2021-12-16T16:00:00.000Z to 2021-12-27T11:00:00.000Z
Saved 260 candles from 2021-12-16T16:00:00.000Z to 2021-12-27T11:00:00.000Z to binance.csv
```

`binance.csv`

```
1639670400000,48578.61,48717.43,48302.49,48506.58,1778.62433
1639674000000,48506.57,48520.73,48060.0,48084.14,1593.51908
1639677600000,48084.15,48313.29,47862.6,47983.5,1434.94112
1639681200000,47983.49,48129.67,47666.0,47866.01,1763.75104
1639684800000,47866.01,48387.54,47832.34,47929.53,1510.25811
1639688400000,47929.53,48167.75,47900.0,48089.61,766.62189
1639692000000,48089.61,48167.84,47511.0,47821.27,1428.35052
1639695600000,47821.27,47821.27,47532.86,47632.38,1046.44879
...
```

The first timestamp `1639670400000` equals `2017-08-17T00:00:00+08:00`